# Output format of bcftools view

Tags: zip, compression, gzip, bcftools

I am using Bcftools to extract a single sample VCF from a GVCF file.

```
bcftools view -f -Oz -s Sample_name -o output_sample.vcf.gz input_file.vcf.gz
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the format of the output is not Bgzip compressed, despite the use of the -Oz flag to do so.

```
    bcftools index output_sample.vcf.gz
the file is not BGZF compressed
```

Would anyone have an idea of why it is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try

```
bgzip -c outputfile.vcf > outputfile.vcf.gz
```

and do not forget to index your file

```
bcftools index outputfile.vcf.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will just integrate bgzip to my pipeline, and index the file at the end.